# Perl's "not" operator not working as expected with the defined() function

Tags: perl

The following snippet is not working as expected:

```
$k{"foo"}=1;
$k{"bar"}=2; 
if(not defined($k{"foo"}) && not defined($k{"bar"})){
    print "Not defined\n";
}
else{
    print "Defined"
}
```

Since both $k{"foo"} and $k{"bar"} are defined, the expected output is "Defined". Running the code, however, returns "Not defined".

Now, playing around with the code I realized that placing parentheses around each of the `not defined()` calls produces the desired result:

```
if((not defined($k{"foo"})) && (not defined($k{"bar"}))){print "Not Defined"}
```

I imagine this has something to do with operator precedence but could someone explain what exactly is going on?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Precedence problem.

```
not defined($k{"foo"}) && not defined($k{"bar"})
```

means

```
not ( defined($k{"foo"}) && not defined($k{"bar"}) )
```

which is equilvalent to

```
!defined($k{"foo"}) || defined($k{"bar"})
```

when you actually want

```
!defined($k{"foo"}) && !defined($k{"bar"})
```

Solutions:

- `!defined($k{"foo"}) && !defined($k{"bar"})`
- `not defined($k{"foo"}) and not defined($k{"bar"})`
- `(not defined($k{"foo"})) && (not defined($k{"bar"}))`

PS - The language is named "Perl", not "PERL".