# (empty?) return of readline is not caught by control structure

Tags: perl, if-statement, for-loop, filehandle

I have a multidimensional hash containing opened file handles on `SEEK_END` with the intention to always read the latest line without getting to much I/O (what I would get with `tail`).

I'm now going through all of these handles with a `for` loop and calling `readline` on them.

It looks like this:

```
for $outer ( keys %config ) {

    my $line = readline($config{$outer}{"filehandle"});

    if (not defined $line || $line eq '' ){
        next;
    }
    else{
        print "\nLine: -->".$line."<--\n";
        $line =~ m/(:)(\d?\.?\d\d?\d?\d?\d?)/;
        $wert = $2;
    }
}
```

If new content is written into these files, my script reads it and behaves just as planned.

The problem is that `readline` will usually return nothing because there is currently nothing at the end of the file, but my `if` doesn't seem to identify the empty return of `readline` as `undef` as empty -- it just prints nothing, which is would be right because there is nothing in this string, but I don't want it to be processed at all.

Comment: Holy guacamole. Thank you very much. Seems like the simplest answer is the best. I tried so many wierd things and never laid my eye on the `||` Operator. Stupid me right. Works fine now.

Comment: Replacing it with `or` is indeed fine, but I stand corrected as to the order of evaluations -- see the answer by [Borodin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin). See [`operator precedence in perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity)

Comment: See also [Perl's “not” operator not working as expected with the defined() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958603/perls-not-operator-not-working-as-expected-with-the-defined-function)

Answer (score 6):

This is an operator precedence problem. You have used a mixture of low-priority `not` with high-priority `||` so your condition

```
not defined $line || $line eq ''
```

is parsed as

```
not(  defined($line)  ||  ($line eq '')  )
```

which wrongly negates the `$line eq ''` part

It is usually safer to use the lower-priority `and` and `or`, and `not` over `&&`, `||`, and `!`, but a mixture is a very bad idea

You can write either

```
if (not defined $line or $line eq '' ) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
if ( ! defined $line || $line eq '' ) {
    ...
}
```

then all will be well

---

I would prefer to see it written like this, because it loses the unnecessary `else` clause and the `next` statements, and discards lines that contain just space characters

Also note that I iterate over the `values` of the hash. Using the keys is wasteful when they are used only to access the values. You will probably be able to think of a better name for the loop control variable `$item`

And there's often no need for the concatenation operator when Perl will interpolate variables directly into double-quoted strings

```
for my $item ( values %config ) {

    my $line = readline( $item->{filehandle} );

    if ( defined $line and  $line =~ /\S/ ) {

        print "\nLine: -->$line<--\n";

        $line =~ m/(:)(\d?\.?\d\d?\d?\d?\d?)/;
        $wert = $2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a proponent of simple conditions. If it is at all feasible, I avoid compound logical conditions with an associated else so that I don't have to think about set complements etc. So, I would have listed the skip conditions individually:

```
next unless defined $line;
next unless $line =~ /\S/;
```

This kind of thing also tends to keep the number of nested blocks lower which I find improves the readability of code.